# Using the javascript , jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

ご教授お願いします。何をどう書けばいいですか？
したいことは、
1,cookie一覧をページに表示し、
cookieがまだ何も保存されていなかった場合にはメッセージを表示したいです。
(例："まだ保存されていません"のような)
2,最新順が一番上に表示されるようにしたいです、

現状はまだ保存されてない場合は真っ白な画面になってます

下記は登録画面でボタンが押されたら表示する処理のlist.htmlです

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja"><head>
<script src="/js/jquery.cookie.js" charset="euc-jp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() { 
   $(document).ready( function(){
   var ss = $.cookie('favorite');` 
    if (!(ss == true )) {
      $('#list').text('何もクリックされていません');
    } else if (ss = $.cookie('favorite')){
      ss = JSON.parse(ss);
      for (var i = 0; i < fa.length; i++) {
        ss[i] = ss[i].substring(ss[i].lastIndexOf('_0') + 2, ss[i].length);
        var d = ss[i].split('_');
        $('#list').append($('<img src="' + d[1] + '">''));
      };
    }
  });

</script>
</head>
<body class="index" >
<div id="list">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

下記は基本になる登録image.htmlです

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready( function(){
        });

        $('img[src="/images/btn_favorite.png"]').click(function () {

            var index = $('img[src="/images/btn_favorite.png"]').index(this);
            var h2 = $('div.box_text:eq(' + index + ')').children('h2');
            var img = $('div.box_main:eq(' + index + ')').find('img');
            var src_para = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');

            $.cookie.json = true;
            var data = $(h2).text() + '_' + './' + img.attr('src');
            if ($.cookie('favorite') == null) {
                var p = [];
                p.push(data);
                $.cookie('favorite', JSON.stringify(p), {'expires':7, 'path': '/'});
            }
            else {
                var ss = JSON.parse($.cookie('favorite'));
                console.log(ss);
                if (ss.indexOf(data) == -1) {
                    ss.push(data);
                }
                $.cookie('favorite', JSON.stringify(fa), {'expires':7, 'path': '/'});

            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box_main">
<div class="photo"><a href=""><img src="images/A.jpg" ></a></div>
<div class="box_text">
<h2>表品A</h2>
</div></div>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<a href="" class="etc_link"><img src="/images/btn_favorite.png"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<div class="box_main">
<div class="photo"><a href=""><img src="images/B.jpg" ></a></div>
<div class="box_text">
<h2> 商品B</h2>
</div></div>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<a href="" class="etc_link"><img src="/images/btn_favorite.png"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<div class="box_main">
<div class="photo"><a href=""><img src="images/C.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="box_text">
<h2> 商品C</h2>
</div></div>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<a href="" class="etc_link"><img src="/images/btn_favorite.png"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQueryでクッキー(Cookie)を扱う場合は、jQuery Cookie pluginを導入します。

こちらの記事が参考となるでしょう。
[jQueryプラグイン「jquery.cookie.js」でcookieを簡単に扱う](http://www.tam-tam.co.jp/tipsnote/javascript/post3109.html)

なお、本来やりたいこととは、2番目のソースにある内容を実施したいのでしょうか。それとも１番目の内容と２番目の内容を同時に行いたいのでしょうか。

$(document).ready(... で呼び出されるのは１つだけです。複数の $(document).ready( は実行されません。

ですので、想像するに、やりたいことは以下でしょうか。

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() { 
  $(document).ready( function(){
    var ss = $.cookie('favorite');
    if ( ss === undefined ) {
      $('#list').text('まだ何も保存されていません');
    } else { 
      fa = JSON.parse(ss);
      for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
        ss[i] = ss[i].substring(ss[i].lastIndexOf('_0') + 2, ss[i].length);
        var d = ss[i].split('_');
        $('#list').append($('<img src="' + d[1] + '">'));
      };
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: すみませんがそのURLのリンク先が削除されています。
また、jQuery Cookie pluginを導入してまして、問題なく動作はしています、私がやりたいのが何もない場合は＜何もない＞と表示をしたいです！！よろしくお願いします

Comment: リンクを修正しました。
回答にも書きました。

Comment: リンクの修正、回答ありがとうございました。
なんか$('#list').text('まだ何も保存されていません');のコメントが表示されませんでした。

コメントが表示できればどこでも構いません。
お手数かけいたしますがご教授願いします

Comment: 提示していただいたソースをもう一度確認させてもらいました。

$.cookie('クッキー名');で指定していたクッキーがない場合は、nullではなく、undefinedが返されました。

ですので、回答に書いたソースを修正しました。ちなみにJavaScriptでデバッガを実行すると、値の授受ができているのかはすぐにわかりますので、デバッガを使ってテストすると良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！、試させていただきます！！

Comment: 全ファイルを作成して試してみましたがはっぱり難しいです！！
1,cookie一覧をページに表示し、
cookieがまだ何も保存されていなかった場合にはメッセージを表示したいです。
(例："まだ保存されていません"のような)
2,最新順が一番上に表示されるようにしたいです、

Comment: 画像が登録されない場合だけメッセージを表示して、画像が登録されたらメッセージは非表示で画像を表示したいです